# Cannot read property 'compile' of undefined. Can't seem to spot the error

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm working on a hobby project where I'm producing dynamic code that I want Angular to compile.

In chrome I get the following error:
*Cannot read property 'compile' of undefined*.

Here's some code examples.

**JS**

```
$scope.oneC = "<button dynamic='right' id='rightarrow' class='fa fa-arrow-right fa-5x' aria-hidden='true' ng-click='next()' style='float: right;'></button>";
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="one" class="columns" compile="oneC"></div>
```

And in my app.js I have a compile directive that has worked in previous projects where the setup has been the same.

**App.js**

```
kakalunchApp.directive('compile', ['$compile', function ($compile) {
return function(scope, element, attrs) {
  scope.$watch(
    function(scope) {
      // watch the 'compile' expression for changes
      return scope.$eval(attrs.ngHtmlCompile);
    },
    function(value) {
      // when the 'compile' expression changes
      // assign it into the current DOM
      element.html(value);

      // compile the new DOM and link it to the current
      // scope.
      // NOTE: we only compile .childNodes so that
      // we don't get into infinite loop compiling ourselves
      $compile(element.contents())(scope);
    }
);
```

};
    }]);

I have included the $compile keyword in the controller

```
kakalunchApp.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, $window, $compile, $sce)
```

Please tell me if you can spot the error. Thank you in advance!

Comment: I've created a Plunk here: http://plnkr.co/edit/7rtewY?p=preview and the code works well. Just added some text to compiled button to have it visible to screen.
Which version of AngularJs are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Change your directive name from 'compile' to something else.